# How can I write a file to my SD card in Android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-storage

I have a requirement for my Android app to be able to receive files from a server and save them in an arbitrary location on my SD card. When I say "SD card", I don't mean the /sdcard/ directory - AKA /storage/emulated/0/, I mean the physical removable SD card.

My initial attempt:

```
FileOutputStream(File("storage/ABCD-1234", "test_file.txt")).use {
    it.write("Hello world!".toByteArray())
}
```

where "ABCD-1234" is replaced with the actual storage ID string. This gives me an IOException saying permission denied, even though I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted. Fine, there must just be some restrictions on SD card writing access. So I spent most of today researching around the internet for apps which can already do this. And I come across [this one called SSH/SFTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver&hl=en_US&gl=US), using which I was able to push a file to the device's SD card via WinSCP from a laptop over WiFi. The thing is, I can't figure out how to go about requesting this ability in my app. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is targeting Android Q (10), in case it matters at all.

Comment: Is the directory created if it doesn't exist in that `File` constructor? I don't know the answer but I wonder if that's the problem.

Comment: "there must just be some restrictions on SD card writing access" -- we have not had reliable read/write access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) since Android 4.4.

Comment: @spartygw The directory I've specified there is the root directory of the SD card. There is no directory that I can create there.

Comment: @CommonsWare I realise that, but I was curious as to how the SSH Server app circumvents those.

Comment: Use SAF and you can write the whole card.